# angular.js syntax highlighting colors in IDEA / WebStorm editor

Tags: intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, phpstorm, webstorm

How can I change the editor colors of angular.js framework in intellij IDEA or WebStorm IDE ?

Take a look at these colors (IDEA screenshot):
[image: current colors]

You can see that **ng-controller** has the same color as **data-attribute** BUT their values have different colors (highlighting). So it is true that the IDE recognize angular.js directives and distinguish their syntax from regular html attributes. I want to be able to control this syntax colors highlighting. I can't find anything related to angular.js inside Settings->Editor->Font & Colors?

For example, Netbeans do it this way (Netbeans screenshot):
[image: Netbeans recognize angular.js directives]

Comment: @CrazyCoder - can you help with it?

Comment: That would be fantastic...